# Associating Django user with another user

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, django-users

How should I go about associating a Django user with another user of the same type? are foreign keys still applicable to be used in this situation?

Comment: You can use foreign keys, sure, but first clarify what do you mean when you say "associate"?

Comment: Well what kind of relation do you want? One-to-many? Many-to-many? One-to-one?